# passing arguments into recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, settimeout

So I have a recursive function using `setTimeout()` and I cannot figure out how to continue to pass my argument into the recursive function that `setTimeout()` is calling.  I tried using `.bind(null, time)` and passing the argument that way but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried using the third option available for setTimeout that I thought was for passing in variables but that doesn't seem to work either. I will try to explain with my code example...

All I am using this function for is a way to set different timeout delays..

```
function delay(t) {
    return (500 - (t * pattern.length));
}
```

this is what is causing me the trouble

```
function next(time) {
    //random code ~turn on//

    setTimeout(function() {
        //random code ~turn off//

        if(score < 50) { 
        setTimeout(next.bind(null, time), delay(time));
        }
    }, delay(time));
}
```

And when I call the function

```
next(30)
```

The `//random code ~turn on` part of my code runs fine, but then it almost seems like the setTimeut function is running without any delay at all.  Like the `time` variable (30) isn't being passed in.  Also I am getting no error codes in the console.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wonder if you could fix the second example so its syntax is correct. Because of the missing closing paraths and indenting, it's hard to tell what is nested within what.

Comment: I just noticed that formatting issue as well, I fixed it thanks!

Comment: It's still not correct. What is the parenthesis above the `if` closing? Is the `if` within the timeout or not? And where are the closing parenthesis of the `if`?

Comment: what is score.?

Comment: where is `pattern` variable from?

Comment: you wouldn't have to bind if you use arrow function.

Comment: you don't have to bind if you know that arguments 3+ get passed to the callback :p - e.g. `setTimeout(next.bind(null, time), delay(time))` is `setTimeout(next, delay(time), time)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer ugh sorry, fixed it now...it got a little messed up when I was trying to remove all the bloat to make it easier to read

Comment: how about adding some `console.log` to debug it - say a `console.log(time)` here and there to see what's happening

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that as well and it isn't working right..

Comment: note that with `t=30` if `pattern.length` is anything larger than `16` than your `delay` will be 0

Comment: so adding console logs "isn't working right" - but does it help?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry I was refering to your first comment when I said that doesn't work ie. not using `.bind()` and passing `time` as the third `setTimeout()` argument.

As for using console.logs, I put `console.log(time) inside the first `setTimeout` and it logs it correctly, but as soon as the recursive `next` function gets called by the second `setTimeout()` it logs `undefined`

Comment: Please post all your relevant code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to do something complicated or it you are complicating something simple. But with the code as it is, the biggest problem is that you are shadowing your `time` argument:

```
function next(time) {
    //random code ~turn on//

    setTimeout(function(time) {
        // time is now undefined, because nothing is passed in
        // to to setTimeout third param


        if(score < 50) { 
         // time here no longer refers to the `time` passed into
         // next, but rather the undefined value delcared as a parameter 
         // to the callback to setTimeout.
         setTimeout(next.bind(null, time), delay(time));
        }
    }.bind(null, time), delay(time));
}
```

The result is that your timeout get called with undefined delays. Removing that will let it work (if I understand what you are doing). You can also just pass a function into timeout that capture the `time` closure so you don't need bind:

```js
// fake score and delay for demonstration purposes
function delay(t) {
    return t;
}

function next(time) {
    setTimeout(function() { // don't pass a paran here (or if you do, rename it)
        let score = Math.random()
        console.log("running", score)
        if(score < .80) { 
           setTimeout(next.bind(null, time), delay(time));
        }
    }, delay(time));
}
next(1000)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think that it is probably a little bit of both honestly, probably closer to over complicating something simple.

I do want two timeouts per cycle, so that is correct.  I think I understand what you are saying but I am still getting `undefined` on the recursion.  I updated my question to show what I changed.  I think I am still missing something...

Comment: @TravisJames the problem is `setTimeout(function(time)` the function being passed to setTimeout is taking a parameter `time`, but nothing gets passed into *that* function. So *that* time is undefined. Now when you try to use `time` inside the timeout, you have overwritten the original `time` passed into  `next()` with undefined.

Comment: okay right, that makes sense and I am following you. Check my question again and I updated it to remove the unneeded ‘time’. However it is still not working and I must be missing something. Can you just tell me if what I have updated in my question should work? Or if I still did something wrong. And then I will Mark this as the answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey @TravisJames, yes, the recursion in your edited answer works for me with values subbed in for `score` and `delay()`. You might double check the values being returned from `delay()` to make sure they are what you are expecting.

Comment: okay thanks and just to verify you aren’t using ‘bind’ or passing in a third argument to ‘setTimeout’  because you used an arrow function which doesn’t have its own ‘this’ value? So none of that is needed?

Comment: @TravisJames `this` doesn't really come into play here.So arrow function or bind should work. I edit my snippet so it's calling setTimeout the same way your question is. Hope it helps a bit. It should keep recursing until `random() returns something larger than 0.8.